# What is the proper way to delete a React element?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a list, and I need to delete an element to be deleted.

The delete button works in that it sends the delete request to the server.  However, a page refresh is needed to have it delete from the front end.

I want it deleted after the delete button is clicked.

I could simply set a boolean on the front end as follows:

```
render && <ComponentToDelete />
```

and change `render` from **true** to **false**.

Is this the preferred way or is there a best practice or more standard way.

I'm simply doing a delete on an item as part of CRUD operations.

I'm not sure if this is relevant:

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#unmountcomponentatnode

Also, per comment here is how the list is generated:

```
    let render;
    if(new_articles.length > 1){
      render = new_articles.map((val, index) => {
        return <ComponentArticle key={index} data={val}/>;
      });            
    }
    return render;
```

[google search here](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C5CHFA_enUS895US895&sxsrf=ALeKk00lomTvrZ_UWucPeiYpvOIxktf_8Q%3A1605671914732&ei=6pu0X9uHLIGctgWcw5zQDw&q=react%20how%20to%20unmount%20%2F%20delete%20a%20component&oq=react%20how%20to%20unmount%20%2F%20delete%20a%20component&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIFCAAQzQIyBQgAEM0CMgUIABDNAjIFCAAQzQI6BAgAEEc6BAgjECc6BggAEAgQHjoECAAQHjoGCAAQDRAeOgQIIRAKULxAWNhPYPBhaABwA3gAgAFeiAHFBZIBATmYAQCgAQGqAQdnd3Mtd2l6yAEIwAEB&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwjbpOmAmovtAhUBjq0KHZwhB_oQ4dUDCA0&uact=5)

Comment: You'll need to show us code. How you're storing the list data in state, how you're rendering them and how you're deleting them

Comment: You are probably using an array to store the list of items initially. You just need to delete the item from that array.

Comment: since you already have new_articles as an array - by removing the element in the array - the render function will automatically update the frontend.

Comment: Ok you added how you render them, but still not how you're storing the data or deleting them...

Comment: Also on another note, you can't use index as the key is the list is going to be dynamic (Google for the answer). The key will have to be something unique for each element

Comment: @cc007 I know, but in React the key is used as the unique identifier for a component. When you change the list, some of the elements will now have a different index (because they'll shift and move as the list changes) but React won't realise that, and you'll get buggy behaviour. Also as per your subsequent comment, you won't be able to change the view without re-rendering, that's how React work. Changes cause re-renders and update the DOM. We really need more code to give specific, useful advice

Comment: @cc007 yes, in React you can't change the view without re-rendering. So will need to re-render in order to show the new list without the deleted element. Some basic precautions can make sure this doesn't cause performance issues, like using `React.memo` or pure components

Comment: React's virtual DOM is smart enough to know if the other list elements don't need to be re-rendered.

Answer (score 1):

As in example above, you just need to remove item from `new_articles`. Let's say the deleted id is deleted_id, You can remove that item from array by trying the following snippet

```js
new_articles.filter((article) => article_id !== deleted_id);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `new_articles` array as state value.

If you make any change to the array, render will update UI automatically.

So after you send delete request to server and get successful response, you can change the `new_articles` array to reflect the deleting.

You can use one of Javascript functions like `fliter` or `splice` with deleted index.